# I get the following error while using esp32

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32

> rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0,
>   SPIWP:0xee
>   clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
>   mode:DIO, clock div:1 load:0x3fff0018,len:4 load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
>   load:0x40078000,len:8896 load:0x40080400,len:5816 entry 0x400806ac
>
> [E][camera.c:1049] camera_probe(): Detected camera not supported.
>   [E][camera.c:1249] esp_camera_init(): Camera probe failed with error
>   0x20004

I tried all the troubleshooting methods found in other forums

Comment: have you tried reading the error printout to determine what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange!

I guess you flashed esp32-cam firmware to off-branded ESP32-CAM with different pinout assignments.

To fix this, maybe you should try around with different settings.

Your code should have something similar to this:

```
// Select camera model
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT
#define CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
```

Now try to comment out the third line, and uncomment the last one. Probably it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever code you have on the ESP32 is looking for a camera. That camera can't be found - is it attached? Did you install the code? Did it come with the code pre-installed? If you installed the code, what code is it? If you didn't install the code yourself, maybe you want to write some new code to get the ESP32 to do what you want it to do.